# Problema con MySQL Workbench

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Estoy con un inconveniente con workbench, ya que no me esta devolviendo en el orden correcto las 'visitas' en mi tabla de estadisticas.

Con MySQL Workbench ordeno de mayor a menor las visitas (haciendo click en 'visitas' en la parte superorior de la columna) y me aparece lo siguiente:

[Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKkTh.png)

Mientras que si lo ordeno con HeidiSQL , me aparece esto:

[HeidiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Nzw.png)

El 'Pelacables WIREFOX...' no me aparece con la ordenacion de MySQL workbench.
Sin embargo , con la consulta

```
SELECT    *
FROM    inv_productos_estadisticas ie
LEFT JOIN inv_productos i ON ie.id_producto = i.id
ORDER BY    ie.visitas DESC;
```

me muestra bien en ambos programas.

Comment: Pero no es que este devolviendo el orden incorrecto. Por que yo veo que el orden está perfecto... Lo que si veo, es que con 1, estás limitando la búsqueda a 1000 filas, mientras que en otra, devuelves 2368 (?) corrígeme si no es así.